# Escape from sandbox: reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, escaping, sandbox, bindingflags

I have really fun problem. It's kind of sandbox escaping.

Aim: get private methods of class

What I can:
1) Load standart assemblies by assemblies by long name
2) Use GetType and Type's methods

What I cannot:
1) Use using in code
2) Use System word in code. When I load assemblies I use such hack Load("Sys" + "tem....")

Looks like I could load private methods like

```
myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

but I haven't BindingFlags imported in my code.

OK, I could create instance of BindingFlags and use GetField of it, but again it returns Object and I can't cast it to BindingFlags.

```
var value = bindingFlagsType.GetField("NonPublic").GetValue(null); //it's Object not BindingFlags
```

I tried Convert.ChangeType method, but Invoke return Object :)

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: I´m not sure what your problem is. The Disposable object which you are getting can be casted into IDisposable. Public Methods u get with GetMethod(...) Popreties with GetProperty(...)

Comment: Write `System.Reflection.BindingFlags...` instead?

Comment: @MaxMustermann, the problem is that I want to get private method of class, that for I need to use BindingFlags that is not imported

Comment: @thehennyy...looks like solution, but I have restriction №2. Add it to topic

Comment: Can you do casts? Then just cast the return of GetValue or cast the underlaying integer to BindingFlags like `(BindingFlags)123`.

Comment: @thehennyy, no, I can't. Casts are possible when import is done. I cant't reference BindingFlags in my code